# parallel_for writing to an unsorted vector

Tags: c++11, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2013

I have a `parallel_for` loop that iterates through a large vector, analyses different portions of it (all possible sequential sequences, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, etc.) and stores statistic information about those portions in another, unsorted vector (using `push_back`). That vector is then sorted after the `parallel_for` loop ends. Isn't this possible? But I get strange readings, the size of the unsorted vector produced is not correct, about 2% of the necessary iterations are missing (everything is correct with a normal for loop). Part of the problem might be that the `parallel_for` loop has an unequal work load: for example, for a vector with 100 members, the first runs of the outer loop have to iterate through the entire 100 members, while the last runs only have to go from 98-100, 99-100.
Here's a simplified version of the code (I use `unsigned` in the loops because I store them along with the index):

```
vector<patchIndex> indexList;
indexList.reserve(2000000);
parallel_for(unsigned(1), units.size(), [&](unsigned n)
{
    for (unsigned j = 0; j != (units.size() - n); j++)
    {
        patchIndex currIndex;
        for (auto it = units.begin() + n; it != units.begin() + (j + n + 1); it++)
        {
            //calculate an index from the (*it).something
        }
        //some more calculations of the index
        indexList.push_back(currIndex);
    }
});
sort(indexList.begin(), indexList.end(), [](patchIndex &a, patchIndex &b) {return a.index > b.index; });
// at this point Visual Studio says that "sort is ambiguous" but it compiles anyway
```

`indexList.size()` should be `(units.size() + 1) * (units.size()/2)` but it is slightly less. And a bunch of the indexes are just zeros that the algorithm cannot correctly produce. So is it simply impossible to write to a shared vector in a `parallel_for`, as simple as that?

Comment: You **are** synchronizing your writes to indexList, right?

Comment: @TomKnapen of course not -- no sync done above at all.

Comment: You can safely write to a vector in a `parallel_for`, but not by doing `push_back`.  The `vector` must be presized, and you have to write to distinct indexes, or you have to wrap the writes in synchronization.

Comment: I should've added that I'm a complete novice at this, I guess. It didn't intuitively seem so obvious that appending members to a vector where order is unimportant should require synchronization. Does the same apply to all other containers (list, deque)?

Comment: I now simply replaced the vector with concurrent_vector. The problem seems to have gone away. Too good to be true?

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Yakk's suggestion and `concurrent_vector` you could also do this.

```
combinable<vector<patchIndex>> indexList;
```

// In the loop.

```
indexList.local().push_back(currIndex);
```

// When out of the loop.

```
vector<patchIndex> result;
result.reserve(2000000);
indexList.combine_each([&](patchIndex x)
{
   result.push_back(x);
});

sort(result.begin(), result.end()[](patchIndex &a, patchIndex &b) {return a.index > b.index; });
```

I haven't tested whether using concurrent_vector is more performant or combinable. The point is to understand that we could also use lock-free containers for this work.